# Text box 'Object does not support attached text' in Word 2016

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote a vba macro in order to print a number of raffle tickets in word. My vba code:

```
        For I = 1 To 10
            ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = N
            ActiveDocument.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = N
            ActiveDocument.Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = N + 10
            ActiveDocument.Shapes(4).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = N + 10
            ActiveDocument.Shapes(5).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = N + 20
            ActiveDocument.Shapes(6).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = N + 20
            ActiveDocument.Shapes(7).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = N + 30
            ActiveDocument.Shapes(8).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = N + 30
            Application.PrintOut
            N = N + 1
        Next
```

However when I run it, i get the error:

> The object does not support attached text

When I debug, the shapes(8) line of the vba code gets highlighted. The other 7 textboxes are filled correctly, and if I remove that last line of code, it prints fine, but the 8th text box obviously isnt getting filled. What am I missing here?

Comment: So I switched shapes(8) to shapes(9) and it worked. Could there a rogue textbox somewhere on the page? I couldn't find one. Or does word not reassign the indexes after a textbox is deleted?

Comment: My preference for this would be to use a TABLE with cells for the tickets... But FWIW anything that "floats" is a `Shape`, so if there are other things in the document that could account for the index. The index will be the *anchor location*, not the order you see the shapes. If you want to use Shapes I'd name them and work with the names. You might want to try Home/Editing/Select/Select objects to see all the Shapes...

Answer (score 1):

I see this is more than a year old, but if someone lands here from Google search results, I was getting this exception when trying to assign value to `MyShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text`, where `MyShape` was a `ContentControl` of type `Checkbox`. Remember that Checkbox and Picture Content Controls do not support attaching text to them.